# Broadcam wifi Driver help

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

Im setting up ubuntu for the first time. I downloaded the version 12. 
My wifi card is BCM4313
I read the manual on how to get the wifi up and running:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

I downloaded the bcmwl-kernel-source and followed the instructions.

Here is the problem
I cant activate the driver. I get an error: sorry installation of this driver failed check /var/log/jockey.log

and when I check it, terminal says no directory or file found.

I need some help, because I cant get internet on the wifi. I tried google already but it didnt give me any usefull answers.

many thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the exact same duplicate, but the cause and solution is the same. You're running into this because 12.04.3 got updated with a 3.8 kernel and it requires a newer Broadcom driver, not included (bug!).

Comment: Ok, so a relatively fast and easy solution is to just upgrade to 13.04?

Comment: You've got two options here: 1) follow the solution in the Q&A in my first comment, 2) upgrade to 13.04. It's up to you. 13.04 will be end-of-life already on January 2014, whilst 12.04 will remain supported a few years still.

Comment: ok bedankt gert, Im going to try it now